# Display of duplicate questions in frontpage/questions list

Tags: feature-request

There are generally two large classes of reasons for closing a question.

1. The question is genuinely not suitable for the platform, perhaps argumentative, off topic, etc.
2. The question is otherwise a good question, but either was asked before (duplicate) or in the wrong forum (moderator redirected).

Is it possible to modify the software so that in the question listing this two classes are distinguished? Currently, all questions that are closed are labelled [closed] after the question name. And many users (including me) do not make a habit of looking at closed questions. But sometimes the duplicated questions have a master question that is not yet answered in a satisfactory way, and driving new attention to it may bring up better answers. And sometimes users may be able to provide a good answer to the migrated question on the forum which is better suited.

**Proposal**: for questions that are closed by migration or closed as duplicate, the tag after the question name should read, instead of "closed", "migrated" or "duplicate" as appropriate.